# Login with Facebook: Permission denied Error: Permission denied (13)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

This is my code:

```
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{1588534284491691}', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => '{38660cabxxx6ed14c83a6724d1d1}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://whatmovieshouldiwatchtoday.com/fb-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

It gives me the following output:

> Warning: session_start(): open(/home/KC/tmp/sess_u1kfabgn2hoij27v6ju69bnut3, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /home/KC/web/whatmovieshouldiwatchtoday.com/public_html/login.php on line 3
>
> Log in with Facebook!
>
> Warning: Unknown: open(/home/KC/tmp/sess_u1kfabgn2hoij27v6ju69bnut3, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/home/KC/tmp) in Unknown on line 0

I do not understand, what this errors means, and how to fix them. Can someone help me out please?

Comment: remove `{}`from  app_id & app_secret

Comment: Done, but same error @B.Desai

Comment: Now give `/home/KC/tmp` directory write permission

Comment: How I do that sir?

Comment: chmod -Rf 777 /home/KC/tmp

Comment: I write that at the starting of my PHP code??

Comment: No, you run that from the command-line

Comment: Sorry, i don't know what is command line in PHP. Can you tell me or give me link of a good tutorial, where I can get to know, how to do it? I am a bit confused. I need to run it using windows cmd, or install something??? I tried to google, and opened 10+ pages, but found nothing useful

Comment: Well what operating system do you run? This issue isn't really a PHP problem but the setup of your filesystem.

Comment: linux serversir

Comment: search for how to give permission to directory in linux. You will find answer

Comment: Sorry, this is confusing. I am using an Linux server, but i have installed windows on my laptop. All the articles, i found wants me to install linux OS first :/

Comment: Nvm, I asked my hosting provider, he fixed it

Comment: If you're struggling with this kind of thing I'd highly recommend not producing anything on a live server for the public to access. You need to do some proper learning, otherwise you're garunteed to leave some very big holes in your system and put yourself and your users in danger.